# Python SQLite query always returns None

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQL-file (SQLite format 3) that I can query with the DB Browser for SQLite (Windows). Whenever I use Python to access the db I get a Null result.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/tmp/test.sql')
cursor = conn.cursor()

conn.execute('select count(*) from Player')
print("result is:", cursor.fetchone()) # result is: None
```

Every Select statement leads to "result is: None".

Any ideas?

Bart.

Comment: Should be `cursor.execute(...)`, not `conn.execute(...)`

Comment: it would be helpful to see the structure of ```test.sql```.

Comment: Ah, simpel. Off course. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("select val from table_name where x = 'something';")
result = cursor.fetchone()

# directly returning result also gives null
if result:
    return result[0]  # tuple returned in result

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```